# Multiple pages to open based on single route laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm very new to Laravel and have a scenario where if a user tries to apply for a job but is not logged in then the user is redirected to an Auth0 login, at this point I want to return the user to a dashboard but also open the job application in a new tab. Is it possible to return two views like this?
I tried to return an array with both redirects in;

```
public function callback(): RedirectResponse
    {
        $redirect_to = session('auth_return_to_url', '/');
        if (str_contains($redirect_to, '/job/view/')) {
            $redirect = [Redirect::intended($redirect_to), Redirect::intended(route('dashboard.dashboard'))];
        } else {
            $redirect = Redirect::intended(route('dashboard.dashboard'));
        }

        try {
            $this->doLogin();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Log::error('Auth0 initialization error', [
                'message' => $exception->getMessage()
            ]);
            return $redirect;
        }

        return $redirect;
    }
```

but this understandably fails with the following message.

`Return value of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth0CallbackController::callback() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse, array returned`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you not add a param to login url. Example

```
login?redirect=%2Fjob%2Fview
```

And after logged in, you can redirect user to url you want.